# Could not load type <something,something> from assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Tags: .net, asp.net, exception

I have problem with this exception that fired in runtime.
i made DLLs in my web applications and it works fine .
BUT when i use these DLLs in windows Service fired this exception:

> Could not load type  from assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

i don't know what is the reason although i compared versions of System.Web in web application and windows service and found they are same.

Thanks advanced.

Comment: Sounds like a referenced DLL is built against .NET while your web app runs under .NET 4. But without more details, it is just a guess.

Comment: Do you use assembly loading across AppDomains?

Comment: i'm using VS2008 .net 3.5 and exception fired in GetType function .I'm using Activator.CreateInstance(BuildManager.GetType(string, true) although it work in web App